# What's the way to deploy a resource once on a helm chart that is deployed multiple times?

Tags: kubernetes, helm

in my use case i've got a helm chart for my application.

One of the resources is actually a **Grafana Dashboard** for the application.

This dashboard actually monitors all instances of the application, and i want it to be deployed only once.

Considering i'm performing 2 **helm install** commands for the same apps, which will cause the dashboard to be deployed **twice**, what's the best practices to have it deployed only once?

- Should it be a totally different "release"? (and be deployed individualy?)
- Should I specify in the 2nd installation not to deploy the dashboard? (seems bad)

What's the best practice?

Answer (score 1):

I've eventually created an umbrella chart with alias:

```
dependencies:
  - name: app
    repository: file://./app
    version: 1.0.0
    alias: child1
  - name: app
    repository: file://./app
    version: 1.0.0
    alias: child2
```

And in values.yaml i've changed the needed values,
then added the grafana dashboard in the bundled yaml file.